# Marketing Cloud does not deliver emails to certain email prefixes

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, transactional-messaging-api

Whenever we try to send emails to adresses like
`mail@something.com`, `info@something.com`, `hello@something.com`,
t he emails are marked as `not-sent`. This is same for transactional emails as well.

For B2B Customers, these are valid ones, and Marketing Cloud should not block them by itself.

Even for B2C, if I have my own domain, I would name it as `hello@mydomain.com`

Customer Support mentioned they need individual email addresses, and they would configured it on their side. Is there a way to control this as a platform owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ask Support to enable [Custom List Detective](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000316767&type=1), as well as add relevant prefixes to a whitelist in CLD, e.g.:

- info
- mail
- contact
- hello
- ...

Providing support with complete email addresses is not needed, above prefixes (and others you find relevant) should be sufficient.

You can use this query in Query Studio to count which prefixes have multiple occurrences in your data, giving you a good indication of which should be provided to support:

```sql
select top 1000 count(id), REPLACE(SUBSTRING(email,1,CHARINDEX('@',email)),'@','') as Name 
from contacts NOLOCK
group by REPLACE(SUBSTRING(email,1,CHARINDEX('@',email)),'@','') 
order by count(id) desc
```

Adding these to CLD whitelist will prevent List Detective from blocking these recipients at sendtime.